# Added file to .gitignore (to not ignore) but git status doesn't see it

Tags: linux, git, raspberry-pi, raspbian

For my project I'm using by .gitignore as a 'don't ignore' file by telling it to ignore everything in the first few lines then giving it a list of file to include with the ! character.  I added a file to my list and copied the file to my working directory and did a "git status" but it's not showing my new file as something to be added.  Even "git status -u" doesn't show anything but says my working directory is clean.

This is on a Raspberry Pi with Debian Wheezy and git version 1.7.10.4, which should be the latest version for Wheezy.  I can do a build of git from the source if that is the fix.

Comment: If you had to take a guess and say what's wrong with your question, what would it be?

Comment: Can you show the content of your .gitignore ?

Comment: I thought one of the things about .gitignore was that you can give it a list of files to not ignore, like this: !./DBQUIKQ.sql
You put a '!' character at the first, then a path to the file you want git to never ignore.  I must be doing this wrong.  This is a new file that is not in the repos yet.  BTW, one of the first lines in my .gitignore tells git to ignore everything, then I give it this list of 'official' files I want it to track.

Comment: Found that if I remove the ./ from the filename, git status now sees my new file.  So, !DBQUIKQ.sql works but not !./DBQUIKQ.sql.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from .gitignore and you will see it, there is no point of putting it there if you want it to be committed.